# Entity Framework Changing from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, domaindatasource

What changes do I need to make to get my entity data model to a new database instance on another server running SQL Server 2008 R2? I have changed the connection string in the Web.config and changed ProviderManifestToken="2008". If I try to refresh or make any changes I am given errors stating that nothing is mapped any more. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some general advice: first migrate the model with data from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 R2 (use any approach, for example, [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/copying-database-sql-2008-copy-database-wizard) or [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/moving-a-database-from-sql-server-2005-to-sql-server-2008-in-three-steps)).
After this create a brand new entity model on SQL Server 2008. Compare the models' XML, make necessary changes in the model created for SQL Server 2005 (maybe you made a mistake in the ProviderManifestToken spelling).
Check that the data types are correspond, and actually that's all.

Comment: This resolved itself after closing and reopening VS 2010. I have no explanation...